# Autowired Spring Data repository w/ H2 database in test not translating Entity table or fields to intended Hibernate naming strategy

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

## Problem

I have a Spring Configuration class that I am using to generate an in-memory H2 database for integration testing.  I also have an integration test that is supposed to use the H2 database for its' methods. One of the tests, a raw JDBC query, succeeds so I know the database is being at least partially generated from scripts.  However, the JPA entity (assume its called SampleThing and has a corresponding SampleThingRepository) does not seem to be using the correct naming strategy when generating SQL.

In the file IntegrationConfigTest I define two tests:

- IntegrationConfigTest.verifyEmbeddedDatabase (passes)
- IntegrationConfigTest.ormMappingShouldWork   (fails with exception org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "sampleThings" not found; )

## Expectation

- What I expect the repository method findOne(1L) to generate for SQL:

  - select samplethin0_.id as id1_6_0_, samplethin0_.is_active as is_active2_6_0_, samplethin0_.name as name3_6_0_, samplethin0_.list_order as list_orde4_6_0_ from testDb.sample_things samplethin0_ where samplethin_.id=?
- What it actually generates:

  - select samplethin0_.id as id1_6_0_, samplethin0_.isActive as isActive2_6_0_, samplethin0_.name as name3_6_0_, samplethin0_.listOrder as listOrde4_6_0_ from testDb.sampleThings samplethin0_ where samplethin_.id=?

In IntegrationConfig I am defining hibernate.naming_strategy to be ImprovedNamingStrategy (which is what I want).  You can assume my entity SampleThing dictates a table name, along with column names, in camel case that should be converted to snake case. Any help would be appreciated.

## Files

Here is IntegrationConfig, my configuration setting up the H2 database:

```
@Ignore("Not a test")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.company.project.repository")
public class IntegrationConfig {
    @Value("classpath:checks_off.sql")
    private Resource checksOffScript;

    @Value("classpath:set_mode.sql")
    private Resource setModeScript;

    @Value("classpath:test_schema.sql")
    private Resource schemaScript;

    @Value("classpath:test_import.sql")
    private Resource importScript;

    @Value("classpath:checks_on.sql")
    private Resource checksOnScript;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Mysql;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false");
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
        return initializer;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(checksOffScript);
        populator.addScript(setModeScript);
        populator.addScript(schemaScript);
        populator.addScript(importScript);
        populator.addScript(checksOnScript);
        return populator;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.company.project");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getPropeties());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties getPropeties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", SpringSessionContext.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "testDb");
        properties.put("hibernate.naming_strategy", org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return properties;
    }


    private JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here is IntegrationConfigTest, the class that contains both tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationConfig.class)
public class IntegrationConfigTest {


    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    SampleThingRepository sampleThingRepository;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    String getThingByOrder(int order) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "SELECT name FROM sample_things WHERE list_order = ?",
            String.class, order);
    }


    @Test
    public void verifyEmbeddedDatabase() {
        String firstThing = getThingByOrder(1);
        assertThat(firstThing, is("This thing"));

        String secondThing = getThingByOrder(2);
        assertThat(secondThing, is("That thing"));
    }


    @Test
    public void ormMappingShouldWork() {
        SampleThing sampleThing = sampleThingRepository.findOne(1L);
        assertThat(sampleThing.getName(), is("This thing"));
        assertThat(sampleThing.getOrder(), is(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your `NamingStrategy` is not being applied. Change `hibernate.naming_strategy` to `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` so that your hibernate properties looks like following;

```
properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy.class.getName());
```